# Measure of an interval contained in a Borel set

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]=\{x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots\}$ and define the open interval
$$G_n=\left(x_n-\frac{1}{2^{n+2}},x_n+\frac{1}{2^{n+2}}\right),\,n\in\mathbb{N}.$$
Putting $G=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}G_n$, define the Borel set $B$ as
$$B=[0,1]\cap G^c.$$
Consider the Lebesgue measure space $(\mathbb{R},\Lambda,\lambda).$
If $I\subset B\cup E$, where $I$ is an interval and $\lambda(E)=0$, then $\lambda(I)=0$.

The book in whick this question appears provides the following hint: "If $I\subset [0,1]$ and $I$ is open, then $I\cap B^c\neq\emptyset$".

To solve this exercise, I suspect it would be necessary to use the following result (which I've already proved):

> Let $G\subset \mathbb{R}$ be an open set and $E\subset G$ such that $\lambda(E)=0$. Then $G\backslash E$ is dense in $G$.

However, I can't see how to proceed from here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Let $E$ be a Lebesgue measurable set such that $\lambda(E)=0$. Let $I$ be an interval such that $I \subseteq B \cup E$.

Let us prove that the interval $I$ has empty interior.

Suppose $I$ has a non-empty interior. Then there is $a, b \in \Bbb R$, $a <b$, such $(a,b)\subseteq I$. It follows that there is $x_n \in \Bbb Q$, such that $x_n \in (a,b)$. So,  $G_n \cap (a,b)$ is a nonempty open interval and so $\lambda(G_n \cap (a,b))>0$.

On the other hand,
$ G_n \cap (a,b) \subseteq (a, b) \subseteq I \subseteq B \cup E$
and
$ G_n \cap (a,b) \subseteq G_n  \subseteq G \subseteq B^c$.
So, we have $ G_n \cap (a,b) \subseteq  E$. Since  $\lambda(G_n \cap (a,b))>0$, we have  $\lambda(E) >0$. Contradiction.

So, the interval $I$ must have empty interior. It means $I$ is a single-point set or the empty set. In both cases, $\lambda(I)=0$.